# Creating a listvliew which has drag-drop feature in Android

Tags: android, listview, drag

Simply how can I create a listvliew which has drag-drop feature to remove items. Some drag-drop listviews are available but not allow you to create your own custom adapter.

Scenario: There is a listview showing the flower image and name on each row. I want to remove each flower from the list by dragging?

Comment: do you mean swipe to delete.

Comment: If swipe to delete, that feature has been in for a while. It's how you clear update messages and other notifications in the notification tray part of the pulldown menu.

Comment: @piyush actually not swiping the view. However, swiping can be used if listview handles with the gap between views. The main problem I face is the custom adapter for listview(I am inflating a row including image and text on it). I can create drag drop listviews if I use  ArrayAdapter<String>. no problem for String rows

Comment: swipe to delete is the best answer for me I solved my problem easily by applying the project ( swipe to delete) by Roman Nurik  https://github.com/romannurik/android-swipetodismiss

Answer (score 0):

There are many custom libraries available in guthub for drag and drop listview:

https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview

https://github.com/mtparet/Drag-And-Drop-Android

https://github.com/willnewii/ListView-DragAndDrop

These are some. Or simply go to www.github.com, search drag and drop listview android and select the one that best suites your need (and also the one which has a good tutorial available :p )

Comment: thanks none of these projects allows dragging drop on Listviews with your custom adapter.

Comment: they do.... everyone of them... drag and drop has nothing to do with adapter.... we have to put our own logic on what to do when user did drag and drop